# jquery not working on server controls in content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am having a TextBox txt on a content page. when i try this

```
$(function(){
$("#txt").focus(function(){alert("abcd"); });
});
```

it doesn't work. It's working if i am using it on simple .aspx page with no master page.

Comment: check the id of that server control , it will have clientid appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the HTML source.  I think the most likely problem is the renaming of the controls by prepending the content section's id.  You can change this with the ClientIDMode property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `"#txt"` is an `<asp:textbox />` control it will get a client id when the page gets rendered, to select an asp.net control you'll need to do `$("[id*='txt']")`